# API object is null when datetime is passed through json

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently trying to create a POST request to create an order.
This works fine if I put my json like this:

```
  "Id": "A2EC1753-88DC-45E1-AD26-F887E0013323",
  "OrderType": "10",
  "Customer": "8111345C-95E3-460F-90FB-26E62E4265C4",
  "CustomerCode": "155542",
  "SubTotal": 417,
  "VatTotal": 0,
  "Total": 417,
 "Created": "2015-03-03T14:01:19.773+01:00",
  "Date": "2015-03-03T14:01:19.773+01:00",
.....
```

But when I give the date like my client is sending (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)
i.e.:

```
"Id": "A2EC1753-88DC-45E1-AD26-F887E0013323",
  "OrderType": "10",
  "Customer": "8111345C-95E3-460F-90FB-26E62E4265C4",
  "CustomerCode": "155542",
  "SubTotal": 417,
  "VatTotal": 0,
  "Total": 417,
 "Created": "2019-04-26 16:53:39",
  "Date": "2019-04-26 16:53:39",
.....
```

The object in my controller returns null.

Created and Date are both of type DateTime.

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

So, the client is sending the DateTime as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.
This is apparently not the default json structure for .Net.

> The spec has objects, arrays, strings, integers, and floats, but it defines no standard for what a date looks like. The default format used by Json.NET is the ISO 8601 standard: "2012-03-19T07:22Z". Prior to Json.NET 4.5 dates were written using the Microsoft format: "/Date(1198908717056)/".15 feb. 2009

I've tried to change it accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/a/49978720/7639883 and the answer below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOData();
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; // month must be capital. otherwise it gives minutes.
            }); 

            Setting.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<IsahContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(Setting.ConnectionString)
            );
        }
```

But for some reason it's still not functioning.

Comment: Most likely the Json parsing isn't lenient about the format. Is there a reason why you can't simply use the first format?

Comment: Unfortunately the client is a 3rd party application and I can not change it.

Answer (score 1):

For Core versions using NewtonSoft.Json (ie. pre-3.0), this article could be useful: https://vikutech.blogspot.com/2017/01/handling-json-datetime-format-on-asp.net-core.html

As described in the article, to direct the Json conversion handled by `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter` class to use custom date formatting, the code below should be added in Configure method:

```
   services.AddMvc()  
   .AddJsonOptions(options =>  
   {  
     options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";  
   });
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take  a look. Do I need to add this piece inside the     ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)?

Comment: I feel like you're right but somehow it's not working just yet.

Comment: It would be better to retype the pertinent details into this answer as links-only answers are not that useful. Stack Overflow doesn't aspire to be google, it aspires to be what Google links to, and as such we should have the answers here.

Comment: I updated the answer a bit to contain the main point from the article. Thanks for the advice @LasseVågsætherKarlsen!

Comment: @Falcon I think this should be the way to change the formatting, I'm sorry to say that I don't really have any further ideas. You could try and create a custom filter in the HTTP pipeline that handles the conversions, but it's a bit of an overkill. And I'm not sure if you can get hook in the process before the conversion is done.